# How to design a 4 input XNOR gate?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image: simplified]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log32.gif))</sub>

[image: open version]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log33.gif))</sub>

I want make this 3 input device 4 input legged. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the boolean expression for what you want?

Comment: You can make it using an inverting 4-to-16 decoder (one where the outputs are active LOW) and a 4-input AND gate...

Comment: @Majenko: If one and only one input high makes a high output, then a 4-to-16 decoder with active low outputs would have to be followed up with a four input NAND, yes?

Comment: No, because it's XNOR so you want a low output not high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the inputs are the same (all high or all low) the output will go high, otherwise the output will g0 low.

[image]

Comment: That's correct for the "other" type of XNOR gate, but the one pictured has "=1" in it, so it's a "one and only one input HIGH" style XNOR gate.

Comment: @Majenko: AARGHHHH!!!

Comment: That's the problem with XNOR / XOR with more than 2 inputs - what does it really mean?

Comment: I was confused, so I went looking for clarification and found [this.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G386.pdf) They use =1 also, but their truth table shows that when A is low, B,C, and Y make an XOR, but when A is high, B,C, and Y make an XNOR, so that: "one and only one input High" rule doesn't seem to be hard and fast. :)

Comment: We had a big long discussion about it all here not so long back: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work/93720#93720