# 3-input XOR gate truth table

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Given the truth table for a 3-input XOR, how come the output is 1 when all inputs are 1? This doesn't logically extend from a 2-input XOR where output is 0 when all inputs are 1. Is there a way to understand this intuitively, or do we need kmaps etc?

[image: xor]
<sub>(source: [electronicshub.org](http://www.electronicshub.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/3-IP-TRUTH-TABLE2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Related http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work

Comment: Always remember XOR is an odd parity detector, For example an XOR with N inputs will output 1 if only odd number of inputs is asserted

Comment: @Elbehery It depends on the definition. And apparently it is ambiguous as the answer in the link above is describing.

Comment: There are two definitions for XOR: just one injput is high, or a odd number of inputs is high. For 2 inputs these definitions coincide, for more than two inputs the world seems to be divide 50-50.

Comment: A niche little trick to remember this can be odd number of ones give the output one. This trick works with any number of inputs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to break it down:  first do \$ A \oplus B = 1 \oplus 1 = 0 \$.  Then we have \$ 0 \oplus C = 0 \oplus 1 = 1 \$.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is **not** a 3-input XOR, it is a cascade of two 2-input XORs. They are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you treat inputs as the **sign** of a number, where the "0" input corresponds to a positive sign, and a "1" corresponds to a negative sign, then the **XOR** function operates as a *multiplier*.
And if you reverse the logical assignment (logic "0" corresponds to -ve sign, and logic "1" corresponds to a +ve sign), that works too.
 But two-input is XNOR, three-input XOR, 4-input XNOR.... I have used a two-input XOR gate as a *multiplying mixer* for two square-wave inputs of differing frequencies. The output contains similar spectral components as an analog type multiplying mixer:
[image: multiply input symbol signs using XOR]
It is strange to me that the accepted symbol of XOR seems to involve addition, when its more fundamental operation is multiplication in my twisted mind.