# 3 Input XNOR gate made with XOR and not gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

hi i have implemented this equation with XOR and Not gate but i'm not getting the correct answers
(A.B.C)+(A'.B'.C')

[image]

What is the Problem ? 
thank you

Comment: There are IC's that have three input XNOR gates, i.e. the 74HC27. What's the purpose of this project?

Comment: we have to design it only with XOR and NOT gate IC's and looks like Y=(A.B.C)+(A'.B'.C') is not 3 input XNOR :(

Answer (score 0):

What you should get is an XNOR gate (Y=A'B'C'+ABC'+A'BC+AB'C) "an even number of ones". As an XOR gate will give an output that is true if and only if an "odd number of ones" is deriving it. So, inverting the XOR gate will results in an XNOR gate that will give an output which is true if and only if an "even number of ones" is deriving it.

Comment: So Y=(A.B.C)+(A'.B'.C') is not 3 input XNOR gate ?

Comment: The logic is wrong for a 3 input XNOR gate. Check this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285392/3-input-xnor-gate-operation