# There's Conflicts in the Definitions of XNOR?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, computer-architecture, boolean-algebra

XNOR has two definitions:

\$1^{st}:XNOR=NOT(XOR)\$

\$2^{nd}: XNOR(A,B)=\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}+A\cdot B\$

The problem is that these definitions are not equal in Odd inputs, the second definition acts as xor at odd inputs.

is the second really a definition or is it just the SOP of the first definition at 2 inputs?

Comment: If you want to ask about odd numbers of inputs, you should make your definitions of the function for an odd number of inputs.

Comment: These *are* equal. The number of inputs here are not Odd. `XOR` with number of inputs greater than 2 has two conflicting definitions indeed. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work/

Answer (score 0):

XNOR is a negation of the Exclusuve OR on any number of inputs. Thus if you have `n` inputs, you perform

A0 + A1 + ... + An

discarding any carry bits from bit 0 (so that result remains to be 0 or 1), and then negate it.

Sounds like you are looking at the two-input implementation (e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Xnor.png)), and it is one of the possible ways to implement XNOR with two inputs. Three input equivalent (and optimized) circuit will look differently.