# In LTSpice, for a 3-input logic gate system, the XOR gate isn't outputting what I'm expecting it to

Tags: ltspice, logic-gates

When A, B and C are all 1, XOR is meant to output 1, but in the simulation it only outputs 0, not 1. Is there something wrong with my schematic?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the manual:

> The exclusive XOR device has non-standard behavior when more than two inputs are used: The output is true only when exactly one of all inputs is true. Use the associative property of XOR's with multiple XOR devices to implement an XOR block with more than two inputs.

I won't bluntly say RTFM, but this should have been the first place to search for an answer, as opposed to posting a question online and waiting for an answer.

Comment: @Jasen The question is related to LTspice and its way of dealing with multiple inputs XOR gates. So, if you think that the implementation is wrong, the best way to deal with it is to write to ADI (since they are now the owners). Otherwise, [Spehro Pefhany's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523928/in-ltspice-for-a-3-input-logic-gate-system-the-xor-gate-isnt-outputting-what/523936?noredirect=1#comment1348611_523928) links to some very nice answers dealing with the generic case of multiple inputs XOR.